# How do I debug Java code running inside a JVM hosted by my C++ application?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface

I have a C++ application that uses the Java Native Interface and creates a JVM in order to execute Java code. How can I debug this Java code while it is being executed within my C++ application? I have all the relevant Java source code, and I'd like to set breakpoints and watch object data within Eclipse.

I've heard of `JDPA` and `JDWP` as tools to accomplish this, but I have no idea about the specific steps. Is there a tutorial for this kind of debugging situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [EclipseZone article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) is a few years old but I think the basic workflow is the same.

Enable remote debugging when starting your JVM within JNI (using the JavaVMInitArgs.JavaVMOption array, see [the spec on JNI_CreateJavaVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp16334)).

You should then be able to follow the EclipseZone steps using localhost as your remote site.

Answer (score -1):

You could run jdb.exe from your c++ application. Here is a nice article that can set you in the right direction.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-06/04-qa-0623-jdb.html

Cheers!